# Which prepositions to use with airline and flight number when speaking of arrival and departure?

Tags: prepositions

I was filling a certain application form and wasn't sure which preposition to use:

> Arrival ***via*** Lufthansa LH 470
>
> Arrival ***with*** Lufthansa LH 470
>
> Arrival ***by*** Lufthansa LH 470

I tried googling and all of them seem to be used equally.

Which preposition should be used here? Can the same preposition be used with **Departure?**

Comment: AndyT's prolly right and also, what form were you filling, please? That might matter here…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use **on**. For example:

> Departed on BA flight 372, returning on Lufthansa LH470.